# Find the homology of $\mathbb C P^n \times \mathbb C P^m.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

> Find the homology of $\mathbb C P^n \times \mathbb C P^m$ without using Künneth formula.

I am trying to use cellular homology to compute the above homology but I couldn't able to proceed further as there are many cells. Is there any clever way to tackle this problem?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Because of the Künneth formula, you only need to find the homology of one $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Is that the part you’re stuck on?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang "without using Künneth formula"

Comment: @Matthew Leingang I am aware of homology of $\mathbb C P^n.$ But the point is that I am not allowed to use Künneth formula.

Comment: What is the differential of a chain complex which is nonzero only in even dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, old eyes. I read “without” but saw “with.”

Comment: @Connor Malin all the differentials are $0.$

Comment: So then I recommend finding out what the cell structure of a product is, because then you are done